# How to model a category and a sub category in Scala

Tags: scala

I try to sort out how to model a category and a sub category.

Here is my current implementation:

```
sealed trait First
sealed trait A extends First
sealed trait B extends First
case object A extends A
case object B extends B

sealed trait Second[M <: First]
case object A1 extends Second[A]
case object B1 extends Second[B]
case object B2 extends Second[B]
case object B3 extends Second[B]
```

Problems :

- There is some boilerplate for the `First` part
- how to retrieve a `First` from a `Second`
- how to provide type safety

To make it concrete, here are what I want to achieve :

```
def first(s: Second[_]) :  First = ???

case class AObject(s: Second[A])
case class BObject(s: Second[B])
```

Comment: What problem are you running into?

Comment: What are you going to do with your categories? With the information you've provided, it's pretty much impossible to say whether or not the design is good...

Comment: question updated with more details

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe:

```
sealed trait Catg
sealed trait SubCatgOf[X <: Catg] extends Catg

case object A extends Catg
case object B extends Catg
case object C extends Catg

case object A1 extends SubCatgOf[A.type]
case object A2 extends SubCatgOf[A.type]

case object A1x extends SubCatgOf[A1.type]
```

Relying on the `A.type` helps reduce repetition.

For obtaining as an actual tree, you'll have to resort to reflection or some macro magic.

Or you could define it manually like this:

```
case class Node [X <: Catg](
  category: X,
  children: List[Node[_ <: SubCatgOf[X]]]
)

val hierarchy = Node(
  A,
  List(
    Node(
      A1,
      List(
        Node(A1x, Nil)
      )
    ),
    Node(A2, Nil)
  )
)
```

Which could be improved with some pimping. But that's defining it twice... so I would try reflection.

Comment: Thanks. `A.type` makes my day. Any idea for implementing method `first` ?

Comment: @YannMoisan Reflection. Probably some form of: `def first(s: Second[_]) :  First = s.getClass.getSuperTypes...` etc (don't know the details off the top of my head)